# ret.json is not a function at MapSubscriber.project

Tags: angular

I have just upgraded my angular 4 project to Angular 6 and getting  the following error. Could somebody tell me  what the problem is ?

```
core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: ret.json is not a function
    at MapSubscriber.project (SettingsController.ts:24)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:55)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.j
```

I have noticed that I have the following controller methods that map to ret.json. Do i need to make any changes here

```
export class AdminProxy {
        constructor(private _phttp: ProxyHttp) { } 


    upload(input: BinaryTransferObject<Dto.UploadInfo>): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.IdResponse>> {
        return this._phttp.post(`/platform/admin/upload`,input||{}).pipe(map((ret:Response) => <ApiResult<Dto.IdResponse>>({  data: ret.json() , originalResponse: ret })));
    }
    listVersions(query: Dto.FileQuery): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.FileDescription[]>> {
        return this._phttp.post(`/platform/admin/list`,query||{}).pipe(map((ret:Response) => <ApiResult<Dto.FileDescription[]>>({  data: ret.json() , originalResponse: ret })));
    }
    reupload(input: Dto.ReuploadRequest): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.IdResponse>> {
        return this._phttp.post(`/platform/admin/reupload`,input||{}).pipe(map((ret:Response) => <ApiResult<Dto.IdResponse>>({  data: ret.json() , originalResponse: ret })));
    }

}
```

interface

```
 export interface IdResponse  {

        id: number;
    }
```

ajaxproxy class

This is the ProxyHttp class that is used

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as ngHttp from '@angular/http';
import { of, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'; 

import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { BinaryTransferObject } from './binary-transfer-object';
import * as Dto from './dtos';
import { ProxyProxy } from './generated/ProxyController';

@Injectable()
export class ProxyHttp {

    constructor(private _proxy: ProxyProxy, private _userService: UserService) { }

    get(url: string, _options?: ngHttp.RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<ngHttp.Response> { return this.makeRequest({ data: null, url: url, verb: 'get' }); }

    post(url: string, body: any, _options?: ngHttp.RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<ngHttp.Response> {
        if (body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            return this.binaryRequest({ binary: body, url: url });
        }
        if (body instanceof BinaryTransferObject) {
            return this.binaryRequest({ binary: body.serialize(), url: url });
        } else return this.makeRequest({ data: body && JSON.stringify(body), url: url, verb: 'post', });
    }
    put(url: string, body: any, _options?: ngHttp.RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<ngHttp.Response> { return this.makeRequest({ data: body && JSON.stringify(body), url: url, verb: 'put', }); }
    delete(url: string, _options?: ngHttp.RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<ngHttp.Response> { return this.makeRequest({ data: null, url: url, verb: 'delete', }); }
   upload(url: string, body: any) {
        this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
        const stream = this._proxy.fileUpload(url, body).pipe(map(ret => ret.originalResponse) , catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this._userService.unauthorized();
                return of(null);
            } else {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }));
        return stream;
    }

    private makeRequest(request: Dto.ProxyRequest): Observable<ngHttp.Response> {
        this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
        const stream = this._proxy.proxy(request).pipe(map((ret => ret.originalResponse) ,catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this._userService.unauthorized();
                return of(null);
            } else {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        })));
        return stream;
    }

    private binaryRequest(body: { binary: ArrayBuffer, url: string }): Observable<ngHttp.Response> {
        this._userService.touched.next(null); // touch
        const stream = this._proxy.binaryUpload(<any>body.binary, body.url).pipe(map((ret => ret.originalResponse), catchError((error: any) => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                this._userService.unauthorized();
                return of(null);
            } else {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        })));
        return stream;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ProxyHttp`? If it uses `HttpClient` under the hood to make http requests, then there is no `.json()` method on response - you will get it immediately.

Comment: if i remove the json method , I get the following error Type '{ data: Response; originalResponse: Response; }' cannot be converted to type 'ApiResult<IdResponse>'.
  Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
    Type 'Response' is not comparable to type 'IdResponse'.

Comment: Can you post `ProxyHttp` implementation here? Is it your service?

Comment: i have posted the code

Comment: I also have a method that uses httpClient @Injectable()
export class ProxyProxy {
     constructor(private _nghttp: HttpClient) { } 
    
    
    authenticateWindowsAuth(): Observable<ApiResult<any>> {
        return this._nghttp.get(`/platform/proxy/windowsauth`,null||{}).pipe(map((ret:Response) => <ApiResult<any>>({  data: ret.json() , originalResponse: ret })));
 }

Comment: Well as I said, there is no response `.json()` method when using HttpClient. You should migrate your code fully to HttpClient and remove those `json()` calls. Also, when using `HttpClient`, you will get the response body directly, and your code looks like it wants the full response object instead of just body. To do that, you need to add `{ observe: 'response' }` to your http options (see https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: Sorry I havent understood it. Could you show it relevant to my example. @Injectable()
export class LocalisationProxy {
     constructor(private _nghttp: HttpClient, private _phttp: ProxyHttp) { } 


getAllCultures(): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>> {
        return this._nghttp.get(`/platform/localisation/cultures/all`,null||{}).pipe(map((ret:Response) => <ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>>({  data: ret.json() , originalResponse: ret })));
 }
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should rewrite your `LocalisationProxy` (and all `HttpClient` related code).

See added `{ observe: 'response' }` as http call options (not that for `post/put/patch`, it is 3rd parameter, for get its 2nd) and instead of calling `res.json()`, I just use `res.body` that already contains JS object.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LocalisationProxy {

  constructor(private _nghttp: HttpClient, private _phttp: ProxyHttp) {}

  getAllCultures(): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>> {
    return this._nghttp.get('/platform/localisation/cultures/all', { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => ({ data: res.body, originalResponse: res })));
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting message Generic Type HttpResponse<> requires one type argument

Comment: Just replace the `map` parameter type with `HttpResponse<ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>>`

Comment: I did try that and got this error Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<ApiResult<Culture[]>>, { data: ApiResult<Culture[]>; originalRespon...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<HttpResponse<HttpResponse<ApiResult<Culture[]>>>, { data: ApiResult<Culture[]>; ...'.

Comment: Yeah that is because of wrong `getAllCultures` return type - you are returning object with `data` and `originalResponse` keys. But that was already wrong in the code you provided. IDK what you exactly expect, but for debugging purposes you can use `getAllCultures(): Observable<any>` to make it work.

Comment: The getAllcultures in the original  code was returning <ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>> with data and originalResponse keyswhich is what is expected . It was working fine before the upgrade. The only difference was ret.json() was getting called. All I need to do is remove the ret.json() and get it working

Comment: is this wrong     getAllCultures(): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>> {
        return this._nghttp.get(`/platform/localisation/cultures/all`,null||{}).pipe(map((ret:Response) => <ApiResult<any>>({  data: ret , originalResponse: ret })));
    }

Comment: The above compiles where as this doesnt     getAllCultures1(): Observable<ApiResult<Dto.Culture[]>> {
        return this._nghttp.get<HttpResponse<ApiResult<any>>>('/platform/localisation/cultures/all', { observe: 'response' })
            .pipe(map((res:HttpResponse<ApiResult<any>>) => ({ data: res.body, originalResponse: res })));
    }

Comment: your example does not make sense. `data` and `originalResponse` has same value.

Comment: i removed the typing from http call, try it like that. its hard for me to guess what your interface mean, also your code is too complicated. you should provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve